# Decoding binary data stored in XML by a third party tool

Tags: java, xml, decode, decoding

I'm trying to parse XML files produced by a third party tool ( [HTC Sync Manager][hsm] ) , since said tool refuses to work anymore.

XML parsing is simple enough, but I'm stuck with trying to decode binary image data serialized into those XML files. As an example, I have a 886 character string which I know represents an image. The full string is

`/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAIBAQEBAQIBAQECAgICAgQDAgICAgUEBAMEBgUGBgYFBgYGBwkIBgcJBwYGCAsICQoKCgoKBggLDAsKDAkKCgr/2wBDAQICAgICAgUDAwUKBwYHCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgr/w
AARCAA8AFADASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWm
p6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGV
mZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD9rP2sfh1Y/FX9mbxr8Nrwf8hTw7dKfyJrwX9gS++Bvxf+A9hoen+CtMQ678OrO18R21qnkfarq2a6tLkY/wA9a+iP2ivFx8Cfs9eOPGFr10zw5d
zj8Lc4r8+PiVq+tf8ABKGb4Z/tG+GdBtrnRvHXgO20PxLpF3eYtrXXfs1tc/av/JWtobHJiT5S/wCCj3xUHg8azY+CrDUtG1m1vPs15d3d59o/t215/wBKrjvh5Z6F498FWPgXRPFmpaKLnGtWmk+Hrv7P9q+y2v8Ay7Vw/wC2R8ede/ar1bxh/wAJRoWm6dqNrZ3Wo6QdJs//AAKr5I8DfEj4k+JfiPpF9omvalp2oab/AMS6z
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`

Base64 decoding it leads to garbage, so that's not the answer.

How can I decode this kind of data?

Comment: Could you post the entire string?

Comment: Can you also tell us what you know about the image? Height and width and type (photo, icon, etc.) in particular.

Comment: It is quite striking that it's exactly the right character set for base64. But I think we will need the rest of the string to be able to advise any further.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen  - I've added the full image string

Comment: Base64 decoding it doesn't lead to garbage. It's an 80x60 JPG image of a woman holding a child. If you show us the code you're using to obtain the value and decode it, perhaps we will be able to tell you how to fix your code.

Comment: It didn't help that when you posted the initial part of the string, it was wrong! The full string doesn't start with the thing you first posted (`rb...`).

Comment: @JLRishe - yup, the problem was my XML parsing code. Thanks for the info and see my answer for details.

Comment: @chiastic-security - I posted a different image the first time. I had to hunt down for one I think no one will mind being shared. The first one I wasn't sure about, therefore I only posted a substring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it happens, the problem was somewhere else. I am parsing the XML file using a SAX `ContentHandler`, e.g.

```
reader.setContentHandler(new DefaultHandler2() {

            private String currentLocalName;

            @Override
            public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
                    throws SAXException {

                currentLocalName = localName;
            }

            @Override
            public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
                  // read data here
         }
```

My problem was that the `characters` method is invoked multiple times, and the raw image data would be overwritten and only the last part would be kept.

The raw data is indeed Base64 encoded.